# xdg-open para abrir una url devuelve error: "no method available for opening"

Tags: linux, raspberry

En Raspberry Pi 3B, estoy tratando de ejecturar una linea de comando que abra el navegador para abrir una url.

He instalado xdg-open, pero me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported.  ($XAUTHORITY is /home/pi/.Xauthority which is owned by pi.)
[7022:7022:1031/212439.181012:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(90)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported.  ($XAUTHORITY is /home/pi/.Xauthority which is owned by pi.)
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: iceweasel: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: seamonkey: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: mozilla: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: epiphany: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: konqueror: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: chromium: not found
[7067:7067:1031/212440.206943:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(90)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: google-chrome: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: www-browser: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links2: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: elinks: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: lynx: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 870: /usr/bin/xdg-open: w3m: not found
xdg-open: no method available for opening 'http://stackoverflow.com'
```

Tengo como navegadores:
-Chromium Web Browser
-Firefox ESR

No me importa utilizar otro método para ejecurlo.

Un saludo.

Comment: Me acabo de dar cuento que como roor no me funciona, pero sin root si. ¿Debe se así? En este caso no me importa. Gracias.

Comment: si te funciona con root hazlo así y no le des mas vueltas